# How to authenticate Google Sheets using Service Account within Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

[image]

I am trying to create a Google app that will search a keyword in a Google Sheets, request (Column A) and return the response (Column B). The script's working well, but whenever the app is called by an end user it is requesting permission to access the Sheets.

I want to know how end users can access the app without permission and how can I provide the app to use service account to read the spreadsheet within the code?

```
function ReadExcelFile() 
{
  var spreadsheetId = <MySpreadSheetID>;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId); 

  var SearchText='Hello'; 
  var data = sheet.getRange('A:B').getValues(); 
  for(var i in data){
  if(i>0){
    var row = data[i][0];
    Logger.log('Searching for a KeyWord: '+SearchText+' From the SpreetSheet Value : '+row);
    var SearchCount=SearchText.indexOf(row);
    if(SearchCount>-1){    
    var row2=data[i][1];
    Logger.log(SearchCount+' '+row2);
    break;
    }    
   }    
  }  
 }
```

```
Request | Response  
Hello   | Hi Welcome!!  
Hey     | Hey Welcome!!
```

Output would be.. 
`Hi Welcome!!`

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, when you want to use the service account, as one of several methods, how about using this library? https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: Hi Tanike, thanks for your comment, I tried this but I am not sure on how to configure this Oauth2 in my App script.. any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. About ``I am not sure on how to configure this Oauth2 in my App script``, I couldn't understand about your situation. Can you provide about the detail information (what you tried. and the result you tried, and if error occurs, please show it.)? If you can do, please add it to your question. Providing the detail information will help users think of your solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem, I want to read the container bound spreadsheet data and reply back as messages to the end user when they messages to the google chatbot, Finally I solved by this way, it may help.
Here is my appscript.json code

```
{
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
        "version": "26"
      }
    ],
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "chat": {
    "addToSpaceFallbackMessage": "Thank you for adding me"
  }
}
```

and here is the oauth, token access, and query api code

```
var PRIVATE_KEY = 'your service account private key generated Google Cloud Project (GCP) console ';
var CLIENT_EMAIL = 'clien-email';
var ssId = 'Spreadsheet Id which you want to read or write data from end user';


/**
 * Configures the Chatbot service.
 */
function getChatbotService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("sathibhai-bot")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot");
}

/**
 * Configures the spreadsheet service.
 */
function getSpreasheetService() {
 return OAuth2.createService("spreadsheet")
 // Set the endpoint URL.
 .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
// Set the private key and issuer.
 .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
 .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
// Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
 .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
// Set the scope.
 .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets");
}

function readSheet(){
  var service = getSpreasheetService();
  var range = 'Sheet1!A1:D';
  var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + ssId +'/values/' + range;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() } }); 
  var rep = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var values =  rep.values;
  for(row in values)
    Logger.log(values[row][0] + ":" + values[row][1] + ":" + values[row][2] + ":" + values[row][3]); //you can use these data as your requirements
}
```

Note that:

1. Share your spreadsheet with the service account i.i your-service-account@sys-..............iam.gserviceaccount.com (and no need to share to any body except service account)
2. Enable Spreadsheet API in GCP console.

Comment: This method still working? I get this error: Error: Access not granted or expired.